# Voxel Water in unity engine

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I am trying to create a voxel style RPG like the one shown in Cube world. And I am trying to get an efficient low-GPU-intensive way to create Voxel water; like the water shown in these

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCFIchEZk2s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJa2w-7edKA

However instead of Blender in unity. I feel it would be good to use a procedual shader (for foam, and waves, and adapting to players jumping in it) of somesort to be efficient for my uses (Ocean, rivers, lakes etc...). though I cannot think of a way to create this kind of shader. I have attempted to throw toghether a shader however I am not the most experienced in the non-programming field.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shader will not be a good idea for water simulation. I would recommend you use cellular automata to get these water voxel some realistic movement.
Cellular automata works when you divide your world into a grid of cells and every update you change the cell state or position depending on its cell neighbours. There are some good examples of this in games like *Conway's game of life* and *Noita*:

[Conway's game of life Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life)
[Noita trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZBLoffoZLH8)

But I will guess that you are going for more of a 3D
style. There is this voxel game which does water simulations very nice:

[John Lin's voxel engine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1R5WFZk86kE)

Comment: Using compute shaders to solve this problem would be a great idea. It would be a lot faster. Also, John Lin's voxel engine uses this paper if you are looking for something to implement https://yzhu.io/publication/mpmmls2018siggraph/